# Minimize function with parameters: how to properly define constraints on the parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax

I am trying to find a minimum of a function consisting of variables and parameters, where I only want to minimize with respect to the variables while defining constraints on the parameters. To illustrate, here a simple example:

I want to minimize the energy function

```
E = 2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ
```

with respect to Δ, assuming that A and K are positive. Here is my attempt:

```
Minimize[{2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ, {A > 0, Ku > 0, Δ > 0}}, Δ]
```

The code does yield a result that distinguishes between cases of `A,K>0` and cases where that condition is not fulfilled, indicating to me that the constraints are not properly taken into account.

How do I properly define constraints on the parameters, such that the code yields only one solution:

```
{4 Sqrt[A Ku],{Δ ->Sqrt[A/Ku]}}
```

I could not find any documentation on minimizing functions with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the easiest approach is just to simplify the resulting expression with some assumptions noted:

```
Simplify[
   Minimize[{2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ, {A > 0, Ku > 0, Δ > 0}}, Δ],
   Assumptions -> {A > 0, Ku > 0, Δ > 0}]
```

> {4 Sqrt[A Ku], {Δ -> Sqrt[A/Ku]}}

Comment: +1 for this workaround. However, I still would like to see if there is a correct syntax for specifying the constraints such that they are properly considered already in the Minimize function.

Comment: The way you have expressed it is asking Mathematica to only find values of Delta that make Ku and A positive.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to @user21382, but wrapping the whole expression in `Assuming`.  For some reason, the `Minimise` ignores the assumptions, so a Simplification step is still required.

Note that putting the `Ku>0, A>0` is unnecessary (this is like asking Mathematica to find a `Δ` that satisfies these constraints.

```
Assuming[A > 0 && Ku > 0, Simplify[Minimize[{2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ, {Δ > 0}}, Δ]]]
```

Comment: Does that mean that it is not possible to specify assumptions on the parameters within the Minimize function?

Comment: @Felix: I don't know of any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To set global assumptions, you can do:

```
$Assumptions = A > 0 && Ku > 0
```

Then, this statement:

```
Simplify[Minimize[{2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ, {Δ > 0}}, Δ]]
```

returns the correct results. Strangely, this does NOT work without the Simplify:

```
Minimize[{2 A/Δ + 2 Ku Δ, {Δ > 0}}, Δ]
```

I do not know why. This seems like a bug.